# How to make VSCode indent an if statement without brackets?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'd like for VSCode to indent automatically indent when I create a newline in the following case:

```
if(statement)
    func();
```

The default functionality does the following when hitting newline:

```
if(statement)
func();
```

This is a longstanding issue in VSCode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43244

I'd appreciate any kind of hack/extension that can accomplish this behavior. There are other instances of indentation getting mangled in the github issue link, but I only really care about this simple case.

Comment: Still present in `code-1.60.2-1632313693.el7`. Until it's fixed -- it looks like that's what the left pinkie finger is for (e.g. `tab` `:)`

Comment: If I can't find a good solution to this, I'll probably just drop vscode (even after investing about 6 hours so far configuring it!)

Comment: Between you and I, anything you have to hack `.json` files to configure -- it's quite fully-baked yet to begin with.... Whether the editor (any editor, not just VScode) will auto-indent following an `if()` has never been a big issue for me. Instead, I'd rather have one smart enough to preserve the current indent and then allow a quick select and block-indent, unindent with a sane key combo like `ctrl + i` and `ctrl + shift + i`. Geany is a good basic editor (with compile ability), as are kwrite/kate on KDE or on windows notepad++ ain't bad for a 4M installer.

Comment: I also use np++! Though I wasn't too fond of the debugger environment there, and there are times where I just disable auto indenting altogether. For regular programming it's something I can deal with, but i've been configuring an environment for contest programming where i'm pretty particular about having less things to keep track of.

Comment: The editor makes little difference to me since I build and run everything from an open xterm (or open command-prompt on windows). If using VS, then the "VS Developer's Command Prompt sets the build environment for you). Always building, debugging, running from the command-line frees you from whatever "environments" the editor is supposed to provide. To me, and editor is simply supposed to process text. (of course the syntax highlight is a must) Vim, emacs, np++, geany, etc.. are all fine. My personal favorite is kate -- it was perfect in KDE3 and has gotten better...

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do this without installing an extension. There may be a better way that can be done in `settings.json` but I couldn't find it. You can modify a languages configuration directly from the source, which for me was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\cpp\language-configuration.json`. There is a [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) for these files settings. I added the following to my c++ language configuration:

```
"onEnterRules": [
        {
            "beforeText": "^\\s*(?:if|while)\\(.*\\)\\s*$",
            "action": {
                "indent": "indent"
            }
        },
        {
            "beforeText": "(?=)",
            "previousLineText": "^\\s*(?:if|while)\\(.*\\)\\s*$",
            "action": {
                "indent": "outdent"
            }
        }
    ]
```

This works, but unfortunately the official c++ vscode extension `C/C++ for Visual Studio Code` breaks it for some reason.

Below was my initial method of doing this, which breaks too many things to be useful.

```
"indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*if\\(.*\\)\\s*$",
        "decreaseIndentPattern": "(?!)"
    }
```

The field `decreaseIndentPattern` must be set (here the regex will never capture anything), otherwise it ignores the `indentationRules` field (I guess they never tested whether just one would be set?) Note that these edits need to be done with administrative privleges, and I found VSCode pretty convenient for making them. Also these changes do not take effect until VSCode is closed.

So as it turns out I've run into the same issues mentioned in this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115454. This fix breaks too much other vscode indentation behavior, such as deindenting after the first properly indented line in if statements.

Comment: 1. Doesn't this prevent the indentation with braces? 2. I *think* you can use `(?!)` instead of junk in the second field.

Comment: I thought that might happen too, but it seems these are in addition to some inherent indentation rules, rather than overwriting them. And if that's a regex expression that never triggers then it would be a better solution.

Comment: Just tested `(?!)` and it does indeed work, editing the answer.

Comment: I don't mind working a bit to properly cofigure an editor, but I found I had to do far too much of this kind of brain surgery with vscode.